# Is there a way of passing the superglobal variable through html form?

Tags: php, html, forms, superglobals

According to my experience so far, when a script is called as HTML form "action", it is assigned a new set of superglobal variables.

Is there a way of passing superglobal variables through html form? Additionally, I would like to know what are the differences of calling a PHP script through include/require statement in comparison to calling it as a form action.

Thanks!

Comment: Each page request gets a new clean environment (you are looking for sessions). `include` files run in the same process, scope and thus retain variable state.

Comment: ^^ another option is hidden form fields

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking into this direction, but with so many unknown options available, I rather decided to ask first.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to encode it somehow, just like anything else you want to stick in a text value.  The pure way of doing this with PHP is `serialize()`.  I prefer to use JSON (`json_encode()`) when I can for compatibility with other systems.

Now, what you're asking is probably not something that you want to do.  I cannot imagine any scenario where it makes sense.